# reading only half content while converting encoded zipped string to normal string in java

Tags: java

```
    String request=new String("UEsDBBQACAAIAHhoEEMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAMe1X247bNhD9FWPfs7Ls7GYNMEwpirLZSKTCy3r9xIfEKAJkd4F4W7R/36FuFH2RW/S18IM5Zw6PRsMZUkSf/nz+Mftj//Pw/fXl4016O7+Z7V++vn77/vLbxxtrincPN58woipzin2xTBuMSF2XnBLDpXA5MQQjrh0XOX/kuSUl3qEkBqIZXBQyRhQr8KbIXC1LZ+AJh28HlBwTohmkklYYnMa0Do2Y1CrFBN1hu36K2YMH0ZIzYRyVQsO/D/8IQYRSL+1KSYQzu5rhOxA7AVFuVZ+WncbLe2DFUBxCm4qQqA5oZNXO8RwezgvOFMw7Bw6Y1paLtSPWbKTiZjfmn/qE1oUTtsoa4ciydT5yRRasDqcsDuoMJppXI2UbRWQVVPdqq9WH+XyezheyTn9FyciDDHkaBNs8gc45sCZa11KZEO8Jkiv+yFTQTo6B3q6ZqrgZEXrgUZpgBp3zsLZKkIphYUgpUdKbfYF1tK+/H95en93b/vA2VFqvUEioSZiT4h/7t9nzfvb28y9Iz4AOhAUO8CLASzwL+BKjNRM56M5R0o1QRaAIoNS0IcZqvEDJEYKgpZmThcu4MhucrpqFglaLcejx47plVV3KHVOdKSm1dbtWXavoGSwQh+cIg5KRu5nZthBEGoyg2OTxM8lIyWY5KChOTcsM7p7NwjKdILBgXOauw3O8uIMXOwahI6msmMuIyHGa+jcNNtKkJNBXRbMd+v3jPaz0MTaKrdvv8lwxrTtr4+U6aGjj0LRDnMT0LFdJYTZ+A7nssmJcopHVGk2WktG4KKVUYUpsQpYZGwke2b3ZikaWtplVmUe7gZHbpoubv379fLcNQ8XWbaf3A6BCh214DdhoXEuXyac+iJnfgsZA7+8eGFtx1rdSff5/Df77GvyrJYiTnsRdAcetIdR0Vk25qxWvfGP1h1nO4SiBw4zKnEHv3oP8NVakQxQjsfthlT7cLWOdU1YkYljJ6o0Uw65yTuOE1EhIs4Ed4XycyTVC8J8JMJn0BudpXMmU0/sqmfGSTUU9yRgRLsV92T3yXoj8otc7WUV4OdSbr6tfYCevraZE3FJ5a9etSMxrpm5ZprlheLvd3p6d0xOQvlqCyXWKnq6/5IpfT5ZeMu3W1yrzGkFPVuakV09V5pRTX63Mqww9VXqzSOBC5JdLc9Kr/2FpnvKaqZOlOSb4w2y8pSanN7fuUtdZhRW0+SJrPvgGCzHxxXKfP/gExIt5upw/pHC3ieBBCm5rTkh897753fnjJHIg/4HtZRe3/im95U8sTVXPghun/+5szq8R3LMyRQTdwJ3Ah5oOrAAjKWCxmLOadV/hyQnSAf7aAAdTHigB2erAr/k8/fCOwjhbZ7ZNw/x+tVymKzjZRkQ/ayQaW3HGk/HN+m9QSwcI78e6fhgEAACNDwAAUEsBAhQAFAAIAAgAeGgQQ+/Hun4YBAAAjQ8AAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADFQSwUGAAAAAAEAAQAvAAAARwQAAAAA");
    byte[] resByte=new byte[11474836];

    resByte=Base64.decode(request.toString().getBytes());

    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(resByte);

    byte[] readByte = new byte[11474836];

    ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(input);
    int noofbyteRead = 0;

    if ( zip.getNextEntry() != null )
    {
        noofbyteRead = zip.read(readByte);
    }
    byte[] writeByte = new byte[ noofbyteRead ];
    System.arraycopy( readByte,0,writeByte,0,noofbyteRead);

    zip.close();
    input.close();


    /* String actualXmlmessage = new String(writeByte);*/
    String s1 = new String(writeByte);
    System.out.println(s1);
```

`s1` displays only half of the content.  Why it is not reading the full content?

Comment: it is displaying only half of the content. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Where does Base64 come from?  Can you please include the **full** source code, specifically imports (it's not much extra, right?).

Answer (score 0):

Before even answering the question, let me make some comments:

There is no need to create a new `String` from a String constant.

```
String request= "UEsDBBQACAAIAHhoE....." ;
```

`Base64.decode` does not receive a `byte[]` to hold the result.  So, it is most probably creating the one it returns.  In consequence, `resByte` does not need to be initialized.  `resByte`'s declaration should be just

```
byte[] resByte;
```

That said, and without many more details, instruction `String s1 = new String(writeByte);` will use the **platform default encoding** (this depends on OS and OS configuration if you have not manually set it).  If your encoding is such as UTF-16 (where every character corresponds to 2-bytes), you would be obtaining exactly half the characters the number of bytes in `writeByte` .

If `s1` looks garbled (which is very different to "half the content" or even "just the content", and you should have pointed this out in the question), then this is what's happening almost for sure.

The solution is to use:

```
String s1= new String(writeByte,charSetName) ;
```

Where `charSetName` corresponds to the character set of the very original input (not only before it was base-64-encoded, but even before it was zipped).